# Update div after form send Mootools 1.1 to Mootools 1.2

Tags: javascript, mootools, mootools1.2

I have this Mootools 1.1 script that is updating div after the form is submited ,

tried to convert it to mootools 1.2.4 but the log does not work and I am not getting any errors either

**Mootools 1.1**

```
        $('myform').addEvent('submit', function(e) {

            new Event(e).stop();
            var log = $('log_res').empty().addClass('ajax-loading');
            this.send({
                update: log,
                onComplete: function() {
                    log.removeClass('ajax-loading');

                }
            });
        });
```

**mootols 1.2**

```
        $('myform').addEvent('submit', function(e) {

            new Event(e).stop();
            var log = $('log_res').empty().addClass('ajax-loading');
            this.set('send',{
                update: log,
                onComplete: function() {
                    log.removeClass('ajax-loading');

                }
            }).send();
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
     $('myform').addEvent('submit', function(e) {

        e.stop();
        var log = $('log_res').empty().addClass('ajax-loading');
        this.set('send',{
            url: this.get("action"),
            data: this,
            update: log,
            onComplete: function() {
                log.removeClass('ajax-loading');

            }
        }).send();
    });
```